# Webbrowser Control accessing new window's document

Tags: c#, browser

I am hosting the WebBrowser control in C# winforms application.  After clicking on a button on main page the application opens a new window and rest all the actions happens in new window.  From the C# host application how can I access the Document of new browser window?  The we.bbrowser's Document property still gives me the original document not the new window's document.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have multi tabbed WebBrowser? or the new link open in IE? Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer after googling.

```
SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1 browser = webBrowser.ActiveXInstance as SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1;
browser.NewWindow += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_NewWindowEventHandler(browser_NewWindow);

void browser_NewWindow(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName,
                       ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed)
{
    Processed = true;
    this.webBrowser.Navigate(URL);
}
```

The trick is the native window event handler and do the webBrowser.Nagivate will make it to navigate in the current window itself.

To use SHDocVw namespace Microsoft Internet Controls COM object must be added to project references.